# How to set runtime parameter from NUnit GUI?

Tags: refactoring, nunit

Currently I am working on a large scale refactoring task where WinForms controls are affected. So practically I would like to change 3rd party controls with our custom controls. I extracted an interface from the 3rd party component, and now I am implementing our custom controls. I wrote tests against the extracted interface, and  created a bunch of unit tests which runs against both the old implementation (the 3rd party one) and the new implementation.It would be fine for me if I could use some runtime switch for the tests. What I mean is that I d like to call ShowDialog() at the end of the tests to provide visual feedback on what I did. It would be strictly an option for the developers. Obviously on build servers it would be not used at all.

Is there any way to do this with NUnit? Can I provide runtime parameters on NUnit GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. If you run `nunit.exe /?` you'll see the list of options you can pass to the GUI executable.

```
NUNIT-GUI [inputfile] [options]

Runs a set of NUnit tests from the console. You may specify an assembly or a project file of type .nunit as input.

Options: /fixture=STR Fixture to test

/include=STR List of categories to include

/exclude=STR List of categories to exclude

/config=STR Project configuration to load

/noload Suppress loading of last project

/run Automatically run the loaded project

/runselected Automatically run selected tests or all tests if none are selected

/console Create console display for viewing any unmanaged output

/lang=STR Language to use for the NUnit GUI

/cleanup Erase any leftover cache files and exit

/help Display help (Short format: /?)
```

In regards to providing feedback to developers, I would suggest using `/console` and sending output to `Console.WriteLine()` instead of using `ShowDialog()`. Hope this helps.